# How is it possible for an infinitely large charged plane to cause the same electric field regardless of distance?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Assume there is an infinitely large plane with a charge density $\sigma$. I understand how to derive, using Gauss' Law, that $E = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ is the electric field at a distance $r$ from the plane.

However, intuitively, I don't understand how this could be true. Shouldn't the electric field be more powerful closer to the plane, since the electric field falls of as $\frac{1}{r^2}$? The larger I make $r$, the further it is from every point, meaning the electric field should decrease - shouldn't it?

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about what "infinitely large plane" means in this case.

Comment: But, by making the distance from the plane longer, is the point not becoming further from *every* point on the plane at the same time?

Comment: This is true, but those "far away" charges of the sheet cancel out because the sheet is infinite.

Comment: There is nothing in reality that implements an "infinitely large plane". This is an abstraction that asks you to assume a finite plane and estimate the scaling of the total charge and the fields that are generated by the charge with size. The result may be a bit counterintuitive, though.

Comment: Infinity is a wonderful thing.  It's even more wonderful in mathematics, where it turns out there's an infinite number of different infinities.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way of looking at it:

If you are close to an infinite plane, you may be feeling stronger attraction by every individual part of it, but "more" of those parts are pulling you at a significant angle. This way, a lot of the attraction is canceling out. As it happens (this is anything but coincidence though), these two opposite effects exactly cancel eachother out when you move away from (or closer to) the plane.